# yii2 summernote widget set toolbar options

Tags: php, yii2, yii2-advanced-app, summernote

I am implementing the summernote in Yii2 warped by marqu3s\summernote\Summernote;
https://github.com/undeman/yii2-summernote

but I can't manage to add the toolbar options showing in the summernote documentation:
http://summernote.org/deep-dive/

That how I am trying to use it but when ever I add the toolbar option the toolbar goes away.

```
    $tabReport .= $form->field($model, 'ysk')->widget(Summernote::className(), [
    'clientOptions' => [
        'placeholder' => 'You can write here some important public notes to be display on top of the report...',
        'minHeight' => 100,
        'toolbar' => [
            'style' => ['bold', 'italic', 'underline', 'clear'],
        ],
    ],
  ]
);
```

Any clues?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your array format is wrong:

```
'toolbar' => [
    'style' => ['bold', 'italic', 'underline', 'clear'],
],
```

will produce the js:

```
'toolbar': {'style': ['bold', 'italic', 'underline', 'clear']}
```

To produce the required js use the same structure as you would in javascript i.e:

```
'toolbar' => [
     ['style': ['bold', 'italic', 'underline', 'clear']]
]
```

In the case of your [your answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/41939918/428543):

```
'toolbar' => [
    ['style', ['style']],
    ['font', ['bold', 'italic', 'underline', 'clear']],
    ['fontname', ['fontname']],
    ['color', ['color']],
    ['para', ['ul', 'ol', 'paragraph']],
    ['height', ['height']],
    ['table', ['table']],
    ['insert', ['link', 'picture', 'hr']],
    ['view', ['fullscreen', 'codeview']],
    ['help', ['help']],
]
```

Answer (score 0):

Well looks like the toolbar options have to be posted directly with js.

What i did is to add an id to the main client options:

```
    $tabReport .= $form->field($model, 'ysk')->widget(Summernote::className(), [
    'clientOptions' => [
        'placeholder' => 'You can write here some important public notes to be display on top of the report...',
        'minHeight' => 100,
        'id' => 'ysk-summernote',
    ],
  ]
);
```

and then add the toolbar options via js in my app.js (or even better to register in the view)

```
    $('#book-ysk').summernote({
    toolbar: [
        ['style', ['style']],
        ['font', ['bold', 'italic', 'underline', 'clear']],
        ['fontname', ['fontname']],
        ['color', ['color']],
        ['para', ['ul', 'ol', 'paragraph']],
        ['height', ['height']],
        ['table', ['table']],
        ['insert', ['link', 'picture', 'hr']],
        ['view', ['fullscreen', 'codeview']],
        ['help', ['help']],
    ]
});
```

And works like a charm